# Cannot seem to change props of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I've got the two following components:

> *I'll be skipping `import`s and `export`s in this question for sake of readability*

**Explorer.js**

```
const Explorer = () => {

    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('C');

     let dirArr = [ 
       <Program key={"C"} name="C" isSelected={true}/>, 
       <Program key={"D"} name="D" isSelected={false}/>
     ];



     const changeSelection = (newSelection) => {
        if (selected !== newSelection){
            dirArr = dirArr.map((el) => {
                switch (el.props.name){
                   case newSelection:
                   case selected:
                       return <Program key={el.props.name} name={el.props.name} isSelected={!el.props.isSelected}/>
                   default:
                    return el
                }
            });
         }
       setSelected(newSelection);
     }


    const handleClick = (e) => {
        //TODO: Make sure only <Program> allowed
       changeSelection(e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML);
    }

    return (
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            {dirArr}            
        </div>
    ) 
}
```

**Basically what I'm trying to do, upon clicking to deselect previous highlighted component and highlight the new one.**

Hence inside the `map` I'm flipping `isSelected` prop upon old `selected` element and on `newSelection`

```
 return <Program key={el.props.name} name={el.props.name} isSelected={!el.props.isSelected}/>
```

---

Then here's **Program.js**

```
const Program = (props) => {

    const [name, setName] = useState(props.name);
    const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
    const [date, setDate] = useState('01.01.75');

    const selectedDeterminer = () => {
        return props.isSelected ? { background: 'blue'} : {}
    }

    return (
        <div style={selectedDeterminer()}>
            <section className="program-name">{name}</section>
            <section className="program-size">{size}</section>
            <section className="program-date">{date}</section>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Upon console logging, I'm sure I'm selecting be it the element name or the `el.props.isSelected` correctly, it's just upon the returned map, it doesn't seem to be affecting the result

[image]

Comment: On handleClick function, what is expected by this `e.target.parentNode.firstElementChild.innerHTML`?

Comment: @nehasoni inside the the `Program.js` `<section ...>{name}</section>` where name is equivalent to `props.name` - so in practical example, upon clicking anywhere on the "D" component, the result would be `"D"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you are using static `isSelected` prop - you need to use your state `selected` variable:

```
let dirArr = [ 
   <Program key={"C"} name="C" isSelected={selected === 'C'}/>, 
   <Program key={"D"} name="D" isSelected={selected === 'D'}/>
];
```

Comment: Yup this solved it for me, though to actually take away a lesson from this, could you please elaborate a little on your answer? Because technically, while the assignment was static, I was still changing the value inside the `map()` function. So I'm a bit confused as to why it wasn't working

Comment: Please take a look at this example that I've made, its much better and more generic implementation - https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-darwin-rkokw . Just look at it this way - everything that is shown in react should be based on some kind of state and you should change apperance of it by changing that state so you have single source of truth. So you just need to change selected state, and your component should shown correct data based on that state.

Comment: Awesome. Yeah I know in terms of my implementation a lot of it is still placeholder code (eg. the static assignment in same file of `<"Programs">`). I guess I needlessly overcomplicated the implementation instead of focusing on the basics